# Session data setting in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. How can I set session date in MS SQL Server?

In Oracle I can use `dbms_application_info.set_client_info()` for setting data for particular session. But in MS SQL Server, how can I set session data like Session date to user assigned date?

Comment: Which information specifically are you after?And where do you want to set them?